# Syncfusion v17 Winforms TreeView controls has odd behavior

Tags: winforms, treeview, syncfusion

At work we are upgrading numerous of our applications to run on .NET Core. We upgraded one of our winforms apps which uses SyncFusion controls and we started seeing a strange behavior.
If you create a TreeView control with the parent item not showing a check box, but have the children show a checkbox. When you click the first child it checks all the children under that parent.
Thinking that we had clearly done something wrong in our code, I downloaded the demo apps from Github. Their CheckboxBinding demo seemed similar (parent items with child items with checkboxes). I updated the code to not show the checkbox on the parent items and ran.
To my surprise, we get the exact same behavior.
Has anyone run into this with SyncFusion TreeView control?

Answer (score 0):

We could observe that you are enabling checkbox for child item and disabled for parent item. But while you checking the first child item, it automatically selects all child . We too checked in your provided example, but we could able to observe that on selecting the item in checkbox , it does select only that particular checkbox item and not all other items. Please find the video for the same from following

Video:

https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Checkstate_Treeview-949457604

So kindly check the video and confirm us whether our understanding on the reported behavior is correct. If not, please send us the video that shows the exact issue, it would be helpful for us to proceed on it further. We have ensured it in 17.4.0.55v

Regards,

Vijayalakshmi VR